# watchOS 2 app not installable via TestFlight

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight, watchos-2

I upgraded my project from a WatchKit app to a watchOS 2 app. Everything is working fine, it runs on watchOS 2 on an upgraded Apple Watch. Uploading to TestFlight also works, no complains from Apple.

When I install it from TestFlight, the iPhone app also works fine, but when I click the "Install on Apple Watch" button in Testflight, it goes to the right for a few seconds, then immediately to the left again without any error message. Not even in the device logs.

But what I also saw is, that when I install the app in general via TestFlight, the watchOS 2 app gets install on the watch (I assume, because I enabled the "Automatic App Install" option) and then the watch app works fine. So there doesn't seem to be something wrong with the app itself. But then again, TestFlight shows it as uninstalled and when I uninstall it via the Watch app on the iPhone, I can't install it again in TestFlight.

Anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After lots of trying out things, even doing a new xcode project and redoing all my provisioning profiles, it was something completely else.

I used a watchOS framework for my watchOS 2 app and that seems to be the culprit. Removing it and adding the source code to the watchOS extension has solved the problem. I can install the app now from TestFlight

In short: Do NOT include your own watchOS 2 framework.

Comment: I have an objection for your conclusion. I have 2 watch apps that uses own external embedded framework. One can be installed from test flight, the other is not. I'm inspecting on it.

Comment: And I gave it up. I compared every single details, however I could not find anything that makes different. I was almost crazy to break my Mac. Just avoiding embedded framework for watchOS is best solution for now. It's very annoying and inelegant approach when I have multiple products that requires own common modules. I think this is a bug for test flight which related with App Variants(App Thining)

Comment: Has a proper solution to this problem been found? I don't want to remove the third-party frameworks from the watch app (I can't)